# How to save parameters before direct payment is made and update the table accordingly using paypal direct payment?

Tags: php, cakephp, paypal

I am making payment through my website directly using credit card payment i.e. directpayment method of paypal, users are not send to paypal site for payment.
How can I update the parameters like last created id by sending it to paypal and get the last created id in return from the paypal? I think I cannot depend on session variable to store the received payment. How can I send parameters along with credit card payment and receive the same data to update my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CUSTOM parameter in your request to send any custom data you need (up to 256 characters) and it will be returned by PayPal in [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) notifications.

Comment: array(
 'TIMESTAMP' => '2014-07-22T11:58:23Z',
 'CORRELATIONID' => 'c951a217818ab',
 'ACK' => 'Success',
 'VERSION' => '104.0',
 'BUILD' => '11950065',
 'AMT' => '1.00',
 'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
 'AVSCODE' => 'X',
 'CVV2MATCH' => 'M',
 'TRANSACTIONID' => '0Y33021510899973G'
)
Paypal in do direct payment returns only these fields.

Comment: Right, it doesn't come back in the API response.  If you need it there you could just save the values in session variables or something like that before sending the request so it's still available when you get the response back.  The CUSTOM data would come back in an IPN, though, so you could automate procedures that way.

Comment: I am afraid if the computer crash down as soon as the payment is made before getting response back from paypal. So I want paypal to return back to me with the parameters I send to paypal and notifyurl. I am using <a href="https://github.com/robmcvey/cakephp-paypal/tree/3df62c03c88dbde6b3bde607ae4ff07739a27b15">cakephp plugin</a> by robmcvey.(https://github.com/robmcvey/cakephp-paypal/tree/3df62c03c88dbde6b3bde607ae4ff07739a27b15)
If you have any used case can you provide me the link

Comment: If their computer crashed then you wouldn't be able to work with any response data at all.  Again, that is where IPN would come into play and eliminate that problem.

Comment: I enabled IPN notification url and I added dynamic notify url in direct payment method but still the paypal is not redirecting to the url I specified or nothing is being carried out with the code I have written in the notify url. Have you got any examples of direct payment with credit card and IPN.

Comment: IPN is not a redirection.  It's a silent POST to your listener script.

Comment: IPN can be set for notify_url right. I tried to use notify url and wrote certain code to execute on that url but could not manage to insert it into the database..Its taking my nerves..Thank you for you responses.

Comment: Yes, but it still has to on in the profile.  Have you checked your web logs to see if your script is getting hit but throwing an error?  That's often the case.

Comment: I was testing from localhost so it was not initiating the response. I checked online and it worked. Now I have to verify the data send from IPN and update my table. Do you know any mechanism for the direct payment to verify and update the database.

Comment: Just replicate it all in the sandbox and it'll work exactly the same as it would live so you can be sure it's good.  You can also use the IPN simulator available in your PayPal developer account tools.

Comment: Can you tell me onething? Is it necessary to use IPN for direct payment through credit cards since paypal will return back response quickly. Can we use session variable to insert response returned.
I used (https://gist.github.com/xcommerce-gists/3440401) to track IPN response but I keep getting on Unverified status.

Comment: That would be just fine.